# ZKteco SDK open/close a specific door (Access-Control device)

Tags: c#, zkteco

The application ZKAccess-3.5 has the ability to enumerate doors, and open or close the selected door.

The sdk has this incomplete API:

```
 VARIANT_BOOL ACUnlock(LONG dwMachineNumber, LONG Delay);

 VARIANT_BOOL GetDoorState(LONG MachineNumber, [in,out] LONG* State, [out,retval] VARIANT_BOOL* pVal);
```

How do I select the door I want to open/close? I have 2 doors. I expected a doorID parameter or something like that.

Device: inBio 260 / 2 doors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: [PullSDK Wrapper in C#](https://github.com/MuaazH/ZKTeco_PULLSDK_Wrapper/blob/main/PullSDK_core/AccessPanel.cs), Shows how to use PullSDK

Those functions are not a part of the **PullSDK**.

ZKTeco claims the `standalone SDK` includes `PullSDK` when It does not cover everything (example: `ControlDevice` function).

The **native** dll **plcommpro.dll** is the main dll for the `PullSDK`.
It exports the function `ControlDevice`, that can be used to lock/unlock doors, but the documentation is confusing, I'm not sure how to use it, I will try to decompile ZKAccess3.5 to find that out.

```
int ControlDevice(HANDLE handle, LONG OperationID, LONG Param1, LONG Param2, LONG Param3, LONG Param4, const char *Options)
```

*ZKTeco is not good at what it does (hardware, software, protocols, sdk, docs).*

Comment: I'm upvoting this purely for that last comment. Very true.